# Is there always a legal way to make an open source product integrate against the will of a proprietary vendor?

Tags: united-states, software, open-source-software, eula

This question is tightly related to other questions here. I'm asking for the USA. Rather than questioning a method of evasion, or predicating the question on any specific contract let's assume there is a company called Evil Corp that

1. has a EULA that prevents reverse engineering, and **generally falls in line with the sophisticated and modern hole-free boiler plate that Oracle and Microsoft and Google use.**
2. has people's data.
3. has competition in the market and outside the market (that is to say isn't a monopoly)
4. sells their product with licensed use.

Is there anyway to ease migration outside of Evil Corp? Can the EULA, copyright, and patent law be such that it is illegal for consumers to create an open source product that integrates seamlessly with Evil Corp's products? To what degree are people allowed to create alternative distributions, and write tools to integrate with proprietary products.

**Are there any consumers to push back with?**

I know historically of a few examples, such as the **right** to root a phone, but I don't understand the legal underpinnings and I know there is a distinction in law for software, services/licensed use, hardware, and data.

Comment: I don't have time to answer but I believe your full answer is in here. https://www.eff.org/issues/coders/reverse-engineering-faq anyone is free to run with this

Comment: What methods would be used to create the integration if reverse engineering is off the table?